# How to fix 'HTML 5 Audio pool exhausted, returning potentially locked audio object' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, clone, howler.js

I am trying to clone this particular website called [patatap.com](https://www.patatap.com) as I am learning JavaScript. But i keep getting this error that I don't know how to solve it. It directs me to a [google website](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio) where it says that there was a policy change for 'Auto play Policy Changes'. But I can't quite figure out how to apply the given example in my code as I am using objects and howler.js.

error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKatq.png

I have tried not using objects and directly defining all key press events inside keyDown function using if..else and it works but it gets confusing and messy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Circles</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/circles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/paper-full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/howler.js"></script>
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
var circles = [];
var keyData = {
  a:{
    color: "purple",
    sound: new Howl({
      src: ['assets/sounds/bubbles.mp3'],
      html5:true
    })
  },
  s:{
    color: "green",
    sound:new Howl({
      src:['assets/sounds/clay.mp3'],
      html5:true
    })
  },
  d:{
    color:"yellow",
    sound:new Howl({
      src:['assets/sounds/confetti.mp3'],
      html5:true
    })
  }
}
function onKeyDown(event){
  if(keyData[event.key]){
    var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width, view.size.height);
    var randomPoint = Point.random();
    var point = maxPoint * randomPoint;
    var newCircle = new Path.Circle(point, 500);
    newCircle.fillColor=keyData[event.key].color;
    circles.push(newCircle);
  }
}
function onFrame(event){
  for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].fillColor.hue+=2;
    circles[i].scale(.9);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect that the sounds start playing while I can still make use of objects and howler.js

Comment: Can't see the error can you paste it as text here?

Comment: @NicholasHirras the error message is as typed in the question title; HTML5 Audio Pool exhausted etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  function  onkeyDown add this line:

```
keyData[event.key].sound.play();
```

Hope this will work.